# Android - Unable to perform setOnClickListener on Relative Layout

Tags: java, android, onclick

I am trying to perform setOnClickListener on the relative layout but unable to perform it means there was no response. I tried a log statement to check if it is clicked or not but nothing was shown in `Logcat`.

**Here is XML Code**

```
 <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbarlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="-10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="-10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewProfile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/back_press"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/back_press"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_back" />

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/friendpic"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="-5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/back_press"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_user" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/friendname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/friendpic"
            android:fontFamily="@font/alegreya_sc_italic"
            android:text="Username"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/friendname"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/friendpic"
            android:text="offline"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

**Here is the JAVA code**

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.viewProfile);
relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Log.d("TAG", "onCreate: True");
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(ChatActivity.this, ViewFriendProfile.class);
            intent1.putExtra("friendId", friendId);
            startActivity(intent1);
        });
```

**Note:** I tried it using on `AppBarLayout` but it didn't work on it.

What Should I do? Any Suggestions?

Comment: Post the rest of the class that contains the code above

Comment: @IvanWooll The whole class code is way too big. It is around 700 lines

Comment: How can the user hit the relative layout if there are a toolbar, an imageview and two textviews before it? They will hit one of those four. Or not? And if the layout had a background color would the user see it or would all be covered?

Comment: QQ: Is this only happening when RelativeLayout inside `AppBarLayout `?

Comment: @blackapps  I solved it by adding one more relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following two suggestions

1. Make RelativeLayout clickable

   `android:clickable="true"`
2. Disable ImageButton (which is a child view of RelativeLayout) click event

   `android:clickable="false"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  But, I solved it by adding one more relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

This whole looks like a toolbar and some menus presentation.
If my guess is the case, simply create profile menu using onCreateOptionsMenu() and redirect to that page using onOptionsItemSelect() Listeners.
If this is not the case please ignore my comment